# SELECT query trouble - user login system

Tags: php, mysql

I am just trying to write a simple script that verifies the username and password of a user that has attempted to login...and then starts a session. However,  I am running into some trouble.

When I try to run the script below, SUCCESS does not print out. As if the username and password is incorrect, however, I know for a fact that the username and passwords entered are, in fact, correct.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='.$username.' AND password='.$password.'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}
```

When I try to run the script below however, success prints out twice (which is the number of sample users I have in my db so far), which is correct.

I am guess I have a problem with the AND mySQL query above, however, it seems correct to me... is there a problem with my first query above? if not, than what else might be the problem?

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}
```

Comment: fyi! - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: some people mentioned SQL injection vulnerability, but please also make sure you aren't storing plaintext passwords in your database. even a simple `md5()` is better, but for best results, use a strong encryption scheme and a reasonably lengthy salt.

Comment: I will, thanks for the advice. I am still in beginning phases of creating the website, and haven't taken any security measures yet; I surely plan to in the future, thanks you;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're [parsing variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), not [concatenating](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) them, you don't need the `.`.

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'"
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>`username` is a protected keyword</strike>, try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think you are over complicating the problem :) Please note @Rockets response.

Comment: @MHZ Irrespective to my oversight, the line should answer your problem

Comment: @Bloafer I did not edit your post Bloafer, I appreciate your response, I am not irrespective :)

Comment: @MHZ `irrespective` does not mean anything bad to you, it means that my own statement `username is a protected keyword` was incorrect, however my code was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the gaping [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, you're constructing your query string incorrectly:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='.$username.' AND password='.$password.'");
                                                           ^         ^
```

You're still in "string mode" where the indicated periods are (and for the password section too), so you're embedding literal periods into your query string, instead of doing string concatenation.

Remote the periods, and you'll be better off (but still vulnerable to sql injection):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=\"$username\" AND password=\"$password\"");
```

Obviously, this isn't a great way of inserting data. You should look at mysqli to insert data as a minimum.

Comment: You can use single quotes in the query, instead of having to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

try this line instead:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$username."' AND `password`='".$password."'");
```

Notice the extra `"`'s I've added in. before it was looking for `'.$username.'`